# Replace pd.MultiIndex level 2 with counter

Tags: python, pandas, multi-index

I have a Pandas Series that is MultiIndexed, and looks something like this:

```
 index1   subindex   value
---------------------------
 label1   a          2.0
          b          4.1
          c          2.3
 label2   r1         6.2
          s7         45.1
```

And I want to turn it into the following:

```
 index1   subindex   value
--------------------------------
 label1   0          ('a', 2.0)
          1          ('b', 4.1)
          2          ('c', 2.3)
 label2   0          ('r1',6.2)
          1          ('s7',45.1)
```

So for every sub-index at level 1, I want to replace it with a counter, but first I want to merge the sub-index with the actual value at that position. Is there a simple way to do this in Pandas?

Thanks.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
df.reset_index('subindex').apply(tuple, 1).to_frame('value').set_index(
    df.groupby('index1').cumcount().rename('subindex'), append=True)

                      value
index1 subindex            
label1 0           (a, 2.0)
       1           (b, 4.1)
       2           (c, 2.3)
label2 0          (r1, 6.2)
       1         (s7, 45.1)
```

Comment: Idk why, I just wasn't able to get a tuple when I tried `apply(tuple)`. I think it was my pandas version.

Comment: Hilarious, there are 7 hours left in the day and you are already out of mana.  You are prolific in your voting.

Comment: Amazing. Thank you.